# How to maintain a round robin approach

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a number of lenders stored in my database. I should say that there are only a small number of lenders so I can cache the data easily, without having to do lookups.

However, when a customer applies for a loan, I want to do my first lookup on a different lender each time but in a logical order. For instance:

Lender A
Lender B
Lender C

First customer views Lender A, second customer B, third customer C, fourth customer A again.

The reason behind this is simply to distribute the leads amongst lenders evenly, and if the counter was reset once a day or so, it wouldn't be the end of the world.

Obviously, I could write this information to the database - but is that overkill? Anyone else needed to implement something similar and come up with a simpler solution?

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't you distribute evenly if you picked up a random lender?

Comment: If you did it randomly, you could potentially send every lead to Lender A

Comment: It depends on how many customers there are. With more customers comes a greater probability of even distribution from random assignments.

Comment: Facio - yeah don't ever think that. Read this article on RapGenius about why randomness isn't good. http://rapgenius.com/James-somers-herokus-ugly-secret-lyrics

Answer (score 4):

If you stored an extra column that contains the DateTime a lender was last selected, you can modify the lender selection query to return the lender that was selected the longest time ago. I.e., something like: `Lenders.OrderBy(x => x.LastSelected).First()`

Of course, you'll also have to write back to the database when a lender is selected. Unless you did all of this in one SQL query. Something like this works (edit: just verified - works well):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET LastSelected = GetDate()
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
WHERE Id = (SELECT TOP (1) Id FROM MyTable ORDER BY LastSelected)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since this is all stored in a db, you could add a column, call it **LastUsed** where you store the date/time, then your query would simply get the earliest date, that should return you the next in line to be used, so your data would look something like this

- Lender A, LastUsed = 2013-05-10 5:30pm
- Lender B, LastUsed = 2013-05-15 4:15pm
- Lender C, LastUsed = 2013-05-16 2:00am
- Lender D, LastUsed = 2013-04-20 11:00am
- Lender E, LastUsed = 2013-05-01 5:00pm

By crafting your query to select earliest date, you would get D, and once used you update with today's date, so next will be E, and so on

Answer (score 2):

Well in order to ensure that subsequent assignments are not done randomly and are done in a logical order you determine then you're going to need to store the previous assignees somewhere.

So basically what I would do is have a column in the database called "AssignedTo" and for each assignment I would check that column, and then assign the new lead to the next logical assignee.

Answer (score 1):

It is overkill.

I'm not aware of your situation (where the program will be used, where the database is etc...).
You should use an xml file to store this information. I'd say you give them the number of clients they have a day and then always take the one with the highest priority.

```
<Lenders> 
   <LenderA Clients = "5", Priority = "1"> Jim </LenderA>
   <LenderB Clients = "4", Priority = "2"> Jim </LenderA>
   <LenderC Clients = "4", Priority = "3"> Jim </LenderA>
</Lenders>
```

In this case, the program knows he can't choose

- LenderA because he have more clients.
- LenderC because he have as many clients as LenderB but a lower priority.

If you've never used XML before I recommand you read about [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) to know how to declare a document and [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx.aspx) to retreive the desired nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep a list of lenders that were used, and then filter all lenders based on first list, so you would get only those who have not lended yet. When list of all lenders is equal to used lenders, clear it and start again. You could easily do it in linq something like: `Where(x => !UsedLenders.Contains(x))`

Answer (score 1):

If there is any record inserted into database for customer's visit, then pick ID of that record and take lender with zero-based index equal to ID mod N, where N is the number of lenders.

This method is sometimes used for simple ad rotators. Since ID values are incremented sequentially and independently form all other changes in data, you get a guarantee that all lenders will be evenly visited and also that customers will be sent to lenders in strictly round robin order.

Exceptions are when some ID value is fetched as part of the transaction that is later rolled back, but this simple solution assumes that number of rollbacks is normally close to zero.